# Error 404 even if resource exist

Tags: tomcat, grails, http-status-code-404

I have this /ImageServer deployed on tomcat which is configured for https and is behind a http server.

When I try to hit the url https://rkg.test/ImageServer (internal url), I get 404 not found error. But I don't get this error all the times, sometimes proper page appears. I have deployed a grails application. This application is converting a ppt/pptx/doc/docx/pdf files to images and serving the files. When I hit the url to see the list of images generated, I can see few images and rest of those are blank at first. If I reload that image by right clicking on it and Reload Image/Show Picture, Image appears.

It seems that images are converted properly, But the server is not able to serve all the requests. I am not able to identify the reason. Kindly help.

Comment: anyone.. who can help me???

Comment: Anything disrupting in log files? especially in catalina.out? Have you tried profilling the application(I imagine a list of images from pdf files may cause memory issues)

Answer (score 1):

have you tired reloadable="true"
in your [apache]/conf/Catalina/localhost/ImageServer.xml file

eg ..
ImageServer.xml  content

```
<Context path="/ImageServer" docBase="/home/user/ImageServer" reloadable="true" crossContext="true" />
```